# Make address lines blank if they don't exist (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager, cllocation

My app finds the user's location, and shows the address in a label. The problem is that if something doesn't exist at a certain place, a postal code for example, then the line says `(null)`. How do I make that line blank? I suppose it has to be set to `nil` somehow, somewhere...

Please help!

Here's my code:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

NSLog(@"Location: %@", newLocation);
CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

[geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray<CLPlacemark *> * _Nullable placemarks, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {

        placeMark = [placemarks lastObject];

        NSString *locationString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@\n%@ %@\n%@\n%@",
                                    placeMark.subThoroughfare,
                                    placeMark.thoroughfare,
                                    placeMark.postalCode,
                                    placeMark.locality,
                                    placeMark.administrativeArea,
                                    placeMark.country];

        locationLabel.text = locationString;

    }

    else {

        NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);

    }

}];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and (very) dirty solution, but ones may find it readable:

substitute `placeMark.postalCode,`

with

```
placeMark.postalCode ? placeMark.postalCode : @"",
```

for each element you want nothing (or whatever other string) to appear in case of `nil`.

Or just write custom code to check for each element in local variables.

--

**Edit:**
In the remote case that you actually have a string containing `"(null)"` the you may want to consider checking for this value substituting again each line with:

```
[placeMark.postalCode isEqualToString:@"(null)"]? @"" : placeMark.postalCode,
```

consider anyway that you should really take care of this earlier in your logic, probably some parsing went wrong when creating the placeMark object string members.

Comment: Uhmm you may really have a NSString with "(null)" content then, that's pretty bad, you should check earlier when you create the placeMark object then. In such a case look at the edit in the answer

Comment: Never mind, I made a mistake. It works... But now there is a blank line which kind of ruins it. Can't I just "nil" it somehow?

Comment: nil what? you can make the \n conditional as well. 

`NSString *locationString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@%@%@ %@\n%@\n%@",
                                placeMark.subThoroughfare ?: @"",
                                placeMark.thoroughfare ?: @"",
                                placeMark.postalCode ?: @"",
                                placeMark.postalCode ?@"/n": @"",
                                placeMark.locality ?: @"",`
...
I borrowed vadian code for this.

Comment: please select any of the anwsers then

Comment: If a place doesn't have a number for example, just a street name, there is a space before the street name because it's set to @""...

Answer (score 1):

This code checks all fields for nil (which causes the `<null>` output) and replaces `nil` values with an empty string.

```
  NSString *locationString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@\n%@ %@\n%@\n%@",
                                placeMark.subThoroughfare ?: @"",
                                placeMark.thoroughfare ?: @"",
                                placeMark.postalCode ?: @"",
                                placeMark.locality ?: @"",
                                placeMark.administrativeArea ?: @"",
                                placeMark.country ?: @""];
```

Comment: Each `??`should be `?:`

Comment: Another problem is that the string may end up with blank lines which is probably undesirable.

Comment: @maddy: Right, thanks, I thought ObjC supports the nil coalescing operator, too.

Comment: @vadian You don't need the full expansion. All you needed to do was change the `??` to `?:`.

Comment: While `?:` is not a part of the "C" standard it is suported by clang Objective-C. A GNU extension to C allows omitting the second operand, and using implicitly the first operand as the second. See [Elvis operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator). It is probably better not to use it.

Comment: It still says (null) :/

Comment: @zaph Never mind, I made a mistake... It works. You're right, now there is a blank line instead. Can't I "nil" it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You really need to write code to check for missing fields and handle them appropriately.

Consider that if some of the items are missing there may be blank lines in the resulting string.